# Why is this a martingale.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

So I'm looking at this page http://notesofastatisticswatcher.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/a-martingale-that-tends-to-latex-infty-with-probability-1/ where they have this martingale that goes to $-\infty$ but there is a step where I'm not sure how they conclude something.

So more or less it goes like this. Let $X_{1}=0$ and let
\begin{equation*}
    X_{n}=\begin{cases}
           n^{2}  &\text{with probability $\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}$}\\
           \dfrac{-n^{2}}{n^{2}-1}   &\text{with probability $1-\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}$}
          \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Then we have that $\mathbb{E}(X_{n})=n^{2}\frac{1}{n^{2}}-\left(\frac{n^{2}}{n^{2}-1}\right)\left(\frac{n^{2}-1}{n^{2}}\right)=0$ and $\mathbb{E}|X_{n}|=2$. Now let $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{n}$  then they claim that $S_{n}$ is a martingale and this is where I'm not sure why its a martingale I want to say that the following is true

$$\mathbb{E}(S_{n+1}|S_{n})=\mathbb{E}(S_{n}+X_{n+1}|S_{n})=S_{n}+\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}|S_{n})=S_{n}$$

Since $\mathbb{E}X_{n+1}=0$ but I'm not sure if this is true or not.

Comment: Martingale that tends to latex infinity. Rather peculiar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the general idea, but you need to know something along the lines of "$X_{n+1}$ and $S_n$ are independent" to conclude that $\mathbb{E}(X_{n+1}|S_n)=0$. Knowing just $\mathbb{E}(X_n)=0$ is not enough.

Comment: That's what I thought but I don't know how to show that $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $S_{n}$, if fact I don't think it is but I don't know how to show that it is or isn't.

Comment: @lancewellton I think in that article it is meant to be implicit from context that the $X_n$ are (jointly) independent, which implies that $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $S_n$. They should say so, however.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, but when you say (jointly) independent do you mean mutually independent or pairwise independent?

Comment: @lancewellton Mutually independent. Also I think that $X_n$ is not actually a martingale: I do not see why $\mathbb{E}(X_3|X_2)$ should be $X_2$. $S_n$ is definitely a martingale provided the $X_n$ are jointly independent, however.